# Password hashing over multiple platforms (Andorid, iPhone, W8M)

Tags: c#, android, objective-c, hash, passwords

We are currently developing a web application in .Net which will also have Android, iPhone and Windows Mobile 8 apps to occupancy it. All of these applications need to have a unified login system. Our site and web services will be using SSL but obviously we want to do all we can to make sure user passwords stay safe. As such we are looking for a common password hashing function that can be used throughout the platforms outlined above.

Currently the only common one we have found is SAH256 however I would like to use something a little stronger. C# has the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class which I would like to use (and can be used in the website and Win8 Mobile) but are there any implementations of this for Android/Java and iOS/Objective C? If this can’t be used what would be our next best option?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375004/716216

Comment: Why do they all need the same technology (hash algorithm)? Is that because clients should hash the input password and then check that centrally?  Why not just use SSL and have the central system hash and compare. Can you explain why the same Hash algorithm is required everywhere please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PBKDF2 is not something that fits well in your situation. It is mainly intended to prevent attacks when the attacker already has your data (ie. an encrypted file). It does this by eating up CPU to force a delay during brute-forcing. Because you're performing auth server-side, you can easily save some CPU and just wait a second or two to send an response to the client if they get the password wrong. Just use a salted hash (like HMAC), and you'll be fine.

If you're using SSL, then your passwords are secure. The only way you can do any better is to implement full public-key crypto, which can prevent MITM attacks. SSL even has this built in.

Sending password hashes over a network is not really more secure than sending passwords. Yes, the password text is hidden from attackers, but they've still got the hash and if they have that, they don't need the password. In the case of SSL, your plain text is also protected.

Comment: A good point well made. This makes it much better for our mobile devs as well. Thanks :)

Comment: It is rather hard to do better than SSL, unless you are a *real* cryptography expert. What does 'full public-key crypto' mean anyway? And PBKDF2 is a perfectly valid and standard algorithm that can be used to hash passwords. HMAC is not quite the same as a salted hash. The main point still stands though: send any potentially sensitive information over SSL and above all *make sure you are validating the server certificate properly*. Otherwise you are securely sending stuff to someone you don't know (a potential attacker).

Comment: I didn't mean to say PBKDF2 was an invalid or non-standard algorithm, only that it is not very suitable for what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The password hashing function should be used on your back-end when storing the user's password and comparing during a login attempt.

Login scenerio:

User sends password over SSL via one of the versions of your app.

The back-end server hashes the password that was sent from the user, retreives the stored hash from the data store, compares the hash of the password sent with the stored hash.

Hashes match, user is allowed access, otherwise access is denied.

The SSL encryption prevents exposure of the password during transmission from the client, storing passwords as hashes prevents exposure of user passwords if your database is breached.

Using this scenerio, since the hashing is all done at the back-end server, only one implementation of the hash algorithm is required.

Comment: Password should be hashed immediately after obtained from UI and the plaintext should be cleared or at least released for GC. Counting on one particular technique, even if it's currently the industry standard, isn't such a great practice.  http://www.informationweek.com/security/vulnerabilities/black-hat-security-pro-shows-how-to-bypa/214501930

Comment: @StenPetrov Hashing the password after it's collected doesn't add any security. If the attacker could access the password and send it to the server themselves, they can access the hash and send it to the server.

Comment: @Rawling youre right. The only point to consider though is a user's use of the same password in multiple services. Thus an obtained hash couldn't be used to try and access different services (unless of course hey all use the same hashing algorithm) whereas a clear-text password could be used for that.

Comment: @Rawling this is true and yet it's a different security issue. Middleman replaying data can be mitigated by implementing challenge-response.  I'm not trying to go the depth here, I'm just saying that relying on standard security measures alone will make your environment vulnerable as soon as someone break the standard. A decade ago for example MD5 was considered strong enough, today we have Flame malware that was capable of using its weaknesses to fake certificates and pretend to be a valid update for taget systems.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used it personally, bcrypt appears to have all the implementations you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#See_also

Hope that helps.